# case sensivity incongruity

Tags: postgresql, order-by, collation

I'm trying to learn and understand collations and how postgresql compare and order strings but I'm finding an incongruity and I don't know what I'm missing.

The query:

```
SELECT datname, datcollate FROM pg_database;
```

Returns that all my DB uses en_GB.UTF-8 collation.

And the query:

```
SELECT table_schema, 
   table_name, 
   column_name,
   collation_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE collation_name is not null
ORDER BY table_schema,
     table_name,
     ordinal_position;
```

Returns that all columns have 'C' collation, which means (according to my research) that no collation is specified. So, I supose that the DB collation is used, isn't?

EDIT: My mistake is here. The previous query doesn't return a result for all the columns, only for those which `collation_name` is not null, and the columns with null collation are the ones that inherit the DB collation. So I  was thinking that foo.bar columns had `C` collation but was `null` in fact.

Well, the incongruity comes when I run the query:

```
SELECT "name" FROM foo.bar ORDER BY "name" ASC;
```

Where "name" column datatype is text and foo.bar is a user created schema.table combination. The result it's human-like alphabetically ordered. From a/A to Z/z, no matter if it's upper or lowercase.

But if I run the following query:

```
SELECT "table_name"
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE
    "table_name" ~ 'some_pattern'
    AND table_schema = 'foo'
    AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY "table_name" ASC;
```

It orders the result in machine-like way, comparing byte by byte and therefore ordering uppercase before lowercase.

Why there is that difference? I've seen that the "table_name" column datatype isn't "text" but "name", but I can't find if it has something to do.

Having the DB collation set to en_GB.UTF-8 shouldn't be enough to compare text in a human way?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't put answers into questions. Post an answer. Don't add "EDIT"s, just edit. [ask] [answer] [help]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The collation in PostgreSQL is determined as follows (simplified, for details see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)):

- if there is an explicit `COLLATE` clause, that determines the collation
- otherwise, if a table column was defines with a certain collation, that collation is used
- if the column is not defined with a collation (it has the “default collation”), the database collation is used.

Now the column `bar.name` was not defined with a collation, so `en_GB.UTF-8` is used.

But `information_schema.columns` has columns of type `information_schema.sql_identifier`, which is a domain over the data type `name`, which always uses the `C` collation. So upper case letters are sorted before lower case letters in that query.

To change that, you should explicitly specify the collation:

```
ORDER BY table_schema COLLATE "en_GB.UTF-8",
         table_name COLLATE "en_GB.UTF-8",
         ordinal_position;
```

Comment: is `ORDER BY table_name COLLATE "en_GB.UTF-8"` preferable to `ORDER BY lower(table_name)` for case insensitive ordering purposes?

Comment: Yes, that should be more efficient, because it entails fewer function calls.